# ¿como usar uuid en React?

Tags: reactjs, uuid

estoy empezando con React y solicito de su ayuda. Usando la libreria Uuid, puedo crear un codigo "unico". ¿como puedo asignar un codigo unico a una imagen o una variable?
Me explico: estoy desarrollando una aplicacion de cupones, y quiero poner un uuid a cada cupon.
De antemano gracias por la ayuda.

```
import cupon from './cupon.png'
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';

function App(){

  const unique_id = uuid(); ///Aqui me genera un codigo unico, pero cambia 
                            ///cada que se actualiza la pagina
  return (
     
  <div>
   <table border="1" cellPadding={12}>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src={cupon} className="App-logo2" alt='cupon1'/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.SO], recuerda realizar el [tour]. Revisa [ask]. Debes por lo menos mostrar la parte relevante del código y mostrar que has intentado y que esperas obtener.

Comment: Gracias por la informacion

Comment: En donde están almacenados los cupones? en una base de datos? de donde esperas traer la info de cada cupon? porque ahi es donde debería estar almacenado el uuid de cada uno. No en el componente (a menos que los cupones esten codificados internamente dentro del mismo componente y no vengan de ninguna fuente externa de datos)